# Why removed event called in firestore realtime Listener when new document added in the collection?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read the messages in real time, the problem is when Person A sends a message to Person B the Person B real-time Listener called with an Added event which is totally I get it but why the Removed event also called?

```
 fun readMessagesRealTimeListener(documentID: String, date: Date, senderUser: ChatUser, reciverUser: ChatUser): LiveData<List<ChatMessage>> {
        if (mutableChatMessageList == null) {
            mutableChatMessageList = MutableLiveData()
            val chatMessageList = ArrayList<ChatMessage>()
            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            readMessageListener = db.collection(Constants.CONVERSATION)
                    .document(documentID)
                    .collection("0")
                    .orderBy("data", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(5)
                    .addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { querySnapshot, e ->
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "error in real time listerner: " + e.code);
                        }
                        val source = if (querySnapshot != null && querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites())
                            "Local"
                        else
                            "Server"
                        Log.d(TAG, "source of $source")
                        chatMessageList.clear()
                        if (!querySnapshot?.isEmpty!!) {
                            for (changedSnapshot in querySnapshot.documentChanges) {
                                when (changedSnapshot.type) {
                                    DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> Log.d(TAG, "New message: " + changedSnapshot.getDocument().getData())
                                    DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> Log.d(TAG, "Modified message: " + changedSnapshot.getDocument().getData())
                                    DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> Log.d(TAG, "Removed message: " + changedSnapshot.getDocument().getData())//this log also called when new document added in firestore but why?
                                }

                                var chatMessage = changedSnapshot.document.toObject(ChatMessage::class.java)

                                Log.d(TAG, "message " + chatMessage.message)
                                chatMessageList.add(chatMessage)

                            }
                            mutableChatMessageList?.value = chatMessageList
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "no message found in real time")
                            mutableChatMessageList?.setValue(null)
                        }
                    })
        }

        return mutableChatMessageList!!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess is that you have more than 5 messages in the collection. In that scenario this listener shows the latest 5 messages only:

```
readMessageListener = db.collection(Constants.CONVERSATION)
        .document(documentID)
        .collection("0")
        .orderBy("data", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(5)
```

So now when you add a new message, that new message becomes the latest. And the previously first message is removed from the `QuerySnapshot`.

It's easiest to see if we quickly draw up up the messages. Say you start with these 5:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So your listener gets called with these 5 messages. And now we add a new message `6`. This new message will be added to the `QuerySnapshot`. But that would lead to it having 6 messages, and you only asked for 5. So you get an `ADDED` for `6`, and a `REMOVED` for `1.

```
1 REMOVED
2
3
4
5
6 ADDED
```

And end up with:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: i asume that this remove opraction not cost me money because its happning on clinte side am i right?

Comment: If no document is read on/from the server for the `REMOVED` (which is at the very least the most common case), then indeed it's an uncharged read.

Comment: is there any solution for this , I don't see any solution in the answer , yes this Is happening and its clearly visible